# MacBook pro boot Kernel panic no kext summary

Tags: macos, mac, kernel-panic, kernel

Yesterday my Mac crashed and after trying to turn it on again I recieved a message like this:

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800667b0b2): "VM page 0xffffff800ad5fad0 should not have an error\n"@SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/vm/vm_kern.c:457
>   Debugger called:
>   Backtrace(CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   Can't perform kext scan: no kext sumaryczny
>   BSD proces name corresponding to current thread: unknown
>
> Mac version:
>   Not yet set
>
> Kernel version:
>   Darvin Kernel Version 13.0.0: thu sept 19 22:22:27 pdt 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/release_x86_64
>   Kernel UUID: ...
>   Kernel slide: 0x0000000006400000
>   Kernel test base: 0xffffff8006600000
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 0

And I know there is a similar post and a good answer to that.

I can't access Recovery HD. When I try to do it by hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> while booting, Mac freezes and does nothing except generating a lot of heat around CPU. I can only turn it on, do nothing and wait for the kernel message above.

What can I do?

Comment: General advice on troubleshooting kernel panics is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to boot your Mac from the system DVD and check the internal disk.
The coincidence of `kext scan` failing and the `recovery HD` unreachable
let me diagnose a major disk (and not just filesystem) trouble.
The CPU overheating *might* be a consequence of a fool's `fsck`.

If you don't have a system DVD to boot your Mac (which is the case
since Lion), I advise you to ask a colleague who have the exact same
MacOS X version to build you one.

Comment: Do you think that formatting hard drive and installing OSX from scratch can solve those problems? I'll try that. I've installed a new SSD drive maybe 2-3 months ago. I fear it can cause those problems. But it started after i installed OSX Maverics. It worked well with OSX Lion

Comment: I would first analyze the disk from another one.
If you have Mavericks on a DVD or on an external HDD, start with this.
BTW, when booted from an external disk, you might also check for any errors collected before the crash within `/var/log/system.log`. These error messages may help you target the real problem: hardware or software.